# Nested if in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, devops

I am writing a pretty simple code in batch script and I found out that it fells when I'm writing a nested if.
This is my code:

```
 if !client!==CTRF ( 
   if !db2_domain! EQU 1 (
    call:upgrade_db_for_CTRF !rel_version!>> !log1! 2>&1
   )
 )
```

Is there something wrong in my indentation or maybe I put the parenthesis in a wrong place?

This is what I want to do:

1. if the client is CTRF **and** db2_domain=1
2. call this function: upgrade_db_for_CTRF

Or maybe do you have another idea how to implement AND operator in a different way?

Comment: What is the failure mode? Are you getting an error message? What is upgrade_db_for_CTRF? (is it a separate batch file, or a routine in this one, or an executable, or what?)

Comment: Can we assume you have delayed expansion enabled?

Comment: identation doesn't matter in batch. Your code snipped is fine - given, the variables are defined and there is no error in the `:upgrade_db_for_CTRF` function and of course delayed expansion is enabled.

Comment: You may write an AND operation in a very simple way: `if "!client!+!db2_domain!" equ “CTRF+1” call :upgrade_db_for_CTRF ...`. Of course, the `+`sign is not needed...

Answer (score 0):

Let's use double quotes to ensure we do not capture unwanted whitespace. I am hereby also assuming you activate `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`

```
 if "!client!"=="CTRF" ( 
     if "!db2_domain!"=="1" (
      echo "!db2_domain!"
      echo "!client!"
   )
 )
```

Once you confirm it works, add your call command again. Also please consider adding what failure you experience.

Answer (score 0):

- The parentheses aren't neccessary
- from the code fragment it isn't clear if `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` is invoked
- the use of all the `!` instead of `%` are only required if inside another enclosing code block.
- to be fail safe against undefined vars `client` and `db2_domain` either double quote both sides of the equation or test with `if defined`